# Nodejs: Waterline + Caolan/Async: bind function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, waterline

Using [Balderdashy/Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) and [Caolan/Async](https://github.com/caolan/async/), i'm trying to parallelize severa Waterline queries. Until now, the shorter I found is the following:

```
const tasks = {
    foos: (function(){return this.exec.bind(this);}).apply(Foo.find({foo: "foo"})),
    bars: (function(){return this.exec.bind(this);}).apply(Bar.find({bar: "bar"}))
};
return async.parallel(tasks, function(err, out){
    // Here, err contains the potential error, and out looks like {foos:[...],bars:[...]}
});
```

I've tried to do `bars: Bar.find({bar: "bar"}).exec` but `async` seems to `apply` the function with another object as scope... So I can't find a way to do this in a shorter/simpler way.

Please note that I want to avoid wrapping the function in another by myself, as it is the syntax I want to find alternatives for:

```
bars: function(cb){Bar.find({bar: "bar"}).exec(cb)}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waterline’s `Deferred`s are thenables, so you can and should use them with promises. [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) is an excellent implementation.

```
return bluebird.props({
    foos: Foo.find({foo: "foo"}),
    bars: Bar.find({bar: "bar"})
}).then(function (out) {
    // …
});
```

Yes, even if you want callbacks in general.

```
return bluebird.props({
    foos: Foo.find({foo: "foo"}),
    bars: Bar.find({bar: "bar"})
}).asCallback(function (err, out) {
    // …
});
```

If you have a very good reason for not being able to use promises despite Waterline already using them, I suppose you could attach something to the `Deferred` prototype:

```
var Deferred = require('waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred').Deferred;

Object.defineProperty(Deferred.prototype, 'execBound', {
    configurable: true,
    get: function () {
        return this.exec.bind(this);
    }
});
```

used as:

```
const tasks = {
    foos: Foo.find({foo: "foo"}).execBound,
    bars: Bar.find({bar: "bar"}).execBound
};
return async.parallel(tasks, function(err, out){
    // Here, err contains the potential error, and out looks like {foos:[...],bars:[...]}
});
```

Comment: This is almost what I need... If only the out results could be returned in a dictionnary with the same keys than the tasks, it would be absolutely perfect.

Comment: @AlexandreGermain: `bluebird.props({ foos: …, bars: … })` instead of `Promise.all`, then. (see edit!)

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Both Bluebird & extending Deferred work like a charm, thank you so much!